# What is the difference between 'Inaugurated' and 'launched'?

Tags: difference, word-meaning, word-difference

We usually say,

> Windows 10 has been launched.

Why can't we say,

> Windows 10 has been inaugurated.

**Question 1:** If we can, then why are there two different words for exactly the same thing. In other words why do exact synonyms exist?

**Question 2:** If we can't then what is the difference between *inaugurated* and *launched*? In which situation do we use *inaugurated* rather than *launched*. As user Random explained in his/her comments([1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63117/what-is-the-difference-between-inaugurated-and-launched?noredirect=1#comment120804_63117),[2](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63117/what-is-the-difference-between-inaugurated-and-launched?noredirect=1#comment120815_63117)) sometimes *inaugurated* is used to imply that the thing being *inaugurated* has been tested first and then given for use. If possible please provide reference for this meaning. Also what kind of things are considered importantant so that they get *inaugurated* e.g. does a private hospital, private company, private shop, private mall/govt. mall, new version of Mercedes or some movement started by people or other things which are at the median of being governmental/political and private.

**My Research effort:** I looked in merriam webster dictionary and google translator but could not find the answer to my question.

Comment: it is not exactly the same thing. inaugurated points the fact someone first used it, and he says "It's ok, you can do it now, as I did", whereas "launched" just says "it is now available". The result is the same, everyone can use Windows 10, but it has not been done the same way.

Comment: @Random Could you give me some reference for it. Google says `inaugurate = to begin or introduce something`. Google doesn't say that the thing has been tested first.

Comment: Presidents get inaugurated; operating systems get launched. Two words are rarely interchangeable across all contexts, even when their definitions are very similar.

Comment: @J.R. What should I say. "The new hospital in our city has been _launched/inaugurated_?"

Comment: @user31782 inaugurated.... you definitely inaugurate a building... Whereas you launch a product on the market...

Comment: @Random What is the criteria for deciding whether something would be _inaugurated_ or _launched_?

Comment: when you inaugurate something, you must have the image in mind with an important person shaking hands and cutting a ribbon, in front of photographers... If it is not appropriate to the subject of your sentence, it is probably the wrong word...

Comment: @Random But Windows 10 is also an important thing and very important persons have got to shake hands in front of photographers. Also initially yow was saying that _inaugurated_ implies something has been tested before.

Comment: Yeah, because there is a 2nd meaning, which imply you buy a car (which is not new, whatever), and you "inaugurate it" by driving it for the first time... it means you tested it and is ready-to-use. So you "inaugurate" your car. If the car's constructor inaugurate it, it means he tested it, and say "The product is ok, I tested it personnaly, you can now buy it"

Comment: I'd like to know the reason of downvote though.

Comment: What definitions are you working from? If the definitions aren't identical, your second question is basically "why do synonyms exist?"

Comment: Why are all the interesting questions in the comments? This question could have been one of the better ones on ELL had you simply included those thought-provoking follow-ons as part of your original question – which can still be done with an edit. As for why there was a downvote, try hovering over the downvote button, and ask yourself, does this question show any research?

Comment: @J.R. Thanks for explaining; I've edited the question accordingly. I didn't add those follow-ups before because they originated after your and others comments.

Answer (score 4):

"To inaugurate" is fairly archaic in American English. We say people get inaugurated in political office, or to inaugurate a new policy. I couldn't tell you exactly what the difference is, but I can't remember the last time I heard someone use the word for anything but a new president.

To say something "launched" implies movement, and a certain element of risk. Its usage is metaphoric, as literally speaking only vessels launch. When you "launch" a new software, you are taking it from its safe harbor (the development team) and putting it out into the dangerous seas (the general public). It used to imply adventure and risk, but is now sufficiently commonplace that people don't normally think of it that way. "Released" is a more neutral word for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In business journalism, "inaugurated" is mostly used to announce the startup of a *service* rather than the release [into the distribution channels] of a product:

> Pierce & Crump PLC announce the inauguration of their two-way hydroplane service that will ferry passengers across the Thames at only £5.- a time.  Tickets may be purchased at their docks, adjacent to Tower Bridge.